# ffmpeg hstack globbing pattern output to a single file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a script that successfully combines images of different widths, but with the same heights into a single linear image, using the following command recursively, always amending to the output file one image at a time.

```
ffmpeg -i 20170609T200001Z-DC.jpg -i 20170609T200010Z-DC.jpg -filter_complex hstack output.jpg
```

I would like to be able to use the glob pattern input, and output to a single file, but I'm having difficulty not understanding the output error message for this command.

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -filter_complex hstack output.jpg

Input #0, image2, from '*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:01.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1136x720 [SAR 72:72 DAR 71:45], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_hstack_0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the stack filters for this. They work with distinct inputs. A sequence of images is still a single input. Use the tile filter instead.

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vf tile=15x1 output.jpg
```

where `15` is the number of images. If you don't know beforehand, use a number large enough. And then crop the output. (Some number has to be specified.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually started with the tile filter, but I have not  been able to get it to work when the input images are not the same width. 

If they are the same width, it works great. Is there an option to indicate they are varying widths? I just wind up with one image, and the rest of the space is black.